# Change model data and update a TableView

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5, qtableview

i'm struggling to get this to work. I would appreciate some help.

So, i have a tableView with 4 columns i establish by default when the program starts. Then, my main() calls a function that creates a thread of a function called "scanner", which scan the serial ports trying to find a specific character an arduino sends(the structure is made so it can be posible to have more than one device). If it finds a device, it appends it to a list that will contain the ports where a valid device is connected to, if not, it returns 0("scanner" returns data via Queues as it is running on another thread). Then it calls a function "reader", that is supposed to add a row per device in the list to the TableView, containing data about the device, but i'm new to Qt, and can't seem to figure it out. Here's some code:

Model Class:

```
class RingerTableModel(QAbstractTableModel):
def __init__(self, data=[[]], horizontalHeaders=[], verticalHeaders=[], parent=None):
    QtCore.QAbstractTableModel.__init__(self, parent)
    self.__data = data
    self.__horizontalHeaders = horizontalHeaders
    self.__verticalHeaders = verticalHeaders

def rowCount(self, parent):
    return len(self.__data)

def columnCount(self, parent):
    return len(self.__data[0])

def flags(self, index):
    return QtCore.Qt.ItemIsEditable | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsDragEnabled | QtCore.Qt.ItemIsSelectable

def data(self, index, role):
    if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
        row = index.row()
        column = index.column()
        value = self.__data[row][column]
        return value

def headerData(self, section, orientation, role):
    if role == QtCore.Qt.DisplayRole:
        if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Horizontal:
            return self.__horizontalHeaders[section]
        if orientation == QtCore.Qt.Vertical:
            return self.__verticalHeaders[section]
        else:
            pass

def update(self, dataIn):
    print('Updating Model')
    self.datatable = dataIn
    print('Datatable : {0}'.format(self.datatable))

def emitDataChanged(self):
    self.dataChanged.emit(QModelIndex(), QModelIndex())

# =====================================================#
# INSERTING & REMOVING
# =====================================================#
def insertRows(self, position, rows, parent=QModelIndex()):
    self.beginInsertRows(parent, position, position + rows - 1)

    for i in range(rows):
        #defaultValues = ["prueba" for i in range(self.columnCount(None))]
        self.__data.insert(position, "hola")

    self.endInsertRows()

    return True

def insertColumns(self, position, columns, parent=QModelIndex()):
    self.beginInsertColumns(parent, position, position + columns - 1)

    rowCount = len(self.__data)

    for i in range(columns):
        for j in range(rowCount):
            self.__data[j].insert(position, QtGui.QColor("#000000"))

    self.endInsertColumns()

    return True
```

Reader function:

```
def reader():
x = 1
rowCount = 0
columnCount = 4
cadena = []
v_headers = []
dispositivos = q.get()
if dispositivos == 0:
    print(dispositivos)
    cadena = ["NO DEVICE"]
    v_headers = cadena
    table = [["NO DATA", "NO DATA", "NO DATA", "NO DATA"]]
    h_headers = ["Puerto", "Estado", "Versión de Ensamblado", "Versión de Hardware"]
    model = RingerTableModel(table, h_headers, v_headers)
    ui.tableView.setModel(model)

elif dispositivos:
    for device in dispositivos:
        print(dispositivos)
        rowCount += 1
        cadena.append("Dispositivo n°" + " " + str(x))
        print(cadena)
        x += 1
        for y in range(rowCount):
            v_headers += cadena
        table = [[device[1], "Online", "1.0.0.0", "1.0.0.0"]]
        h_headers = ["Port", "Status", "Assembly Version", "Hardware Version"]

        model = RingerTableModel(table, h_headers, v_headers)
        #ui.tableView.setModel(model)
        #model.update(table)

        #model.emitDataChanged()
        #model.dataChanged()
        #ui.tableView.update()
```

Comment: I see you create a self.datatable variable but you never use it.

Comment: Yes, my mistake. That was something i was trying from another question related i found here but couldn't get it to work.

Comment: If you realize in your loop you are creating a new model instead of inserting it into the model. I recommend creating the model once outside the loop and using your insertRows method inside the loop. Do you speak Spanish?

Comment: And where i set the model? In the main? Yes, i speak spanish and english

Comment: Which main ?, I suppose you have a class where it is implemented ui, in that part declares the model as a member of the class and then you can access through ui.model

Comment: I have a module generated by the Qt Designer and then, i have a file "main.py" where i instanciate  the class of the window

Comment: You could share your code through github, drive or similar to understand you better.

Comment: I uploaded all the project so you can understand better :) https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B7zvhjchewklTjI2UFAtbEc2ZTg

Comment: Why do you create a thread for the scan method? Also why not use the QtSerialPort module?

Comment: The scan method uses a thread to prevent the GUI freezing because it has to continuely scan those ports, except those ports where it already found a valid device(note that the scanner module clearly isn't inside a loop because i forgot to insert it, but that was my intention, that's why i use a thread) . But my problem is with the QTableView and the MVC pattern. Maybe I misunderstood everything and didn't understand how it is supposed to be used?

Comment: My idea is to help you improve your program, if you keep building it this way your code will be immensable. Using threading modules makes software maintenance difficult because they do not meet the minimum requirements Qt requires, it is best to use Qt classes such as QSerialPort and QThread. With the first class it is not necessary to create threads indiscriminately, but this handles signals and slots that is the most correct in Qt.

Comment: First of all, thank you for taking your time to help me with this. So, I'll definitely try to use QSerialPort and QThread. But, what i have to do with the QTableView and the model?

Comment: Well, leaving that point aside another thing that seems strange is that the variable q = Queue () is created but is never filled, and therefore the table is empty and will always be. When you fill the queue?

Comment: It is filled in the scan function. If the list "dispositivos_serie" is empty it will return 0, otherwise it will return the list itself. And then in the method reader() i retrieve the data with the line: "dispositivos = q.get()" and then i use those print to see if it retrieved the data correctly.

Comment: You are sure of what you say, according to what I see in your code is that main import to scanner and scanner import to main, and this always generates an infinite loop. That's why I notice that your program is crashing

Comment: I import the main into the scanner module to access the q variable. But just for that, it doesn't invoke the main method again.

Comment: Even so, only the circular import generates the problems, I recommend not to use global variables indiscriminately.

Comment: Okay, i fixed it by only importing the q variable and the reader method. But i still don't know how to get to work the QTableView

Comment: Wait, I'm trying to improve your code so that it can be read correctly and display the data in the table.

Comment: Wow, i would really appreciate that.